# FORTRAN 90 Open file issues

Tags: file-io, fortran90

I've been searching around this code for long now and can't seem to find the reason of this not working... Maybe an outsiders view can help.

```
!I open File 1

!Opening File 1
open(2, File='File1.txt',status='old')
read(2,*)!File 1 header

PRINT*,'File1.txt read' 

!Read it

DO b=1,nb
  DO i=1,ni(b)          
       READ(2,*)dum(b,i),Qr(1,xbu(b),i),hr(1,xbu(b),i),Ar(1,xbu(b),i),Pr(1,xbu(b),i),dx(xbu(b),i),sx(xbu(b),i)
  END DO
END DO
```

And it's fine. I've printed it, it's all there. But when i go to File 2, doing the exact same thing:

```
PRINT*,'Reading File 2 '
open(3, File='File2.txt',status='old')    !<- It stays here forever.
PRINT*,'File2.txt read'
```

The files are plain txt, with real values like this

File 1:

```
11  0   0   0   0   6500    1.2
```

File 2

```
11  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.0
```

Any thoughts on what could cause the same code to fail the second time?

Comment: Unit numbers less than 10 can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably throw some error checking in there, try putting

```
open(3, File='File2.txt',status='old',iostat=io_status, err=100)
```

And somewhere put

```
100 write(*,*) 'io status = ', io_status
stop
```

I also recommend writing a function which checks for the first available fortran unit number rather than hard coding it in, something like [getting free unit number in fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876075/getting-free-unit-number-in-fortran)

Comment: `err` is pretty much superfluous if you're checking `iostat` (simple `if(io_status/=0)...` statement after `open`). Plus it's awfully reminiscent of fixed-format F77 syntax.