# fortran function to find available file unit

Tags: file, file-io, fortran, fortran90

I can write a FORTRAN function to find an available file unit, but I was certain there was already an intrinsic.  But if there is, I can't find anything about it.  Is there such a thing or am I dreaming?

UPDATE: Apologies for the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876075/getting-free-unit-number-in-fortran).  Did a search, but it didn't show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, you are looking for [newunit](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/newunit) (available with F2008, shown at the bottom of that link in the Fortran Wiki).

Ups, has already [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7876075/577108).

Comment: That's it!  Well, I didn't realize it was a 2008 feature.  I was hoping 90 or 95.  But at least I know I'm not crazy.  (Or at least, the evidence for me being crazy is now diminished by one data point!)  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffIrwin just tested with ifort 15.0.1 and newunit works. Should still work with 16, documentation for it is at: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/580158

Comment: My mistake.  It's `gfortran` that doesn't have `newunit` on my computer, but I'm using version 4.4.7.  Maybe some of the newer versions have it.

Comment: @JeffIrwin Yes, it is in gfortran since 4.5: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Fortran2008Status. I believe it is a fairly simple addition to the compiler and according to the status overview at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2008+status is supported by recent compilers of Cray, IBM, NAG and PGI aswell.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you were thinking of [inquire](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/525317)?

Comment: I know I can use that to write a function to do what I need.  But I thought there was a function that could the whole thing for me.  Maybe I was thinking of some function someone wrote using INQUIRE.  Thanks.