# Count lines within a Fortran loop

Tags: loops, fortran

I have a time series data that goes from 0 to 15000 lines and a few columns. I want to separate the data in intervals of 60 seconds and count the amount of data that are inside each interval.

I created a do loop that correctly creates the intervals of 60s from the beggining to the end of the file, however, I don't know how to count the number of lines that are inside each interval.

The end result that I'm looking for is to have two columns as a result:
interval number and number of lines.

Here is what I got so far:

```
program flash_selection

implicit none       

integer i, zero, qtd, cellnumb, flashcell, tipo, segment

real time, Etrig, xtrig, ytrig, ztrig, poscharge, negq, chargeneutr

open(1,file='my_file.txt',status='OLD') 

read(1,*)                                           

do 

read(1,*,end=100) qtd, time, cellnumb, flashcell, tipo, segment, Etrig, xtrig, ytrig, ztrig, poscharge, negq, chargeneutr

do i = 1, 420

open(2,file='test.txt')

if (time .GE. (i-1)*60 .AND. time .LT. i*60) then

write(2,*) qtd, time, tipo, segment, Etrig, xtrig, ytrig, ztrig, poscharge, negq, chargeneutr

end if

end do 
end do
```

The IF statement correctly separates the data according to what I wanted, the only thing left is to know the amount of lines that there are on each interval of 60.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `counter` variable.  Increment `counter` every time through the loop.  When the IF test is successful, print out `counter` and then set it back to zero.

(BTW -- not sure you want your `OPEN` statement inside the loops.  And you should use file numbers greater than 10.)

Comment: In regard to the unit number, depending on the compiler, it might support automatic unit assignment, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876075/getting-free-unit-number-in-fortran

Comment: Thanks for the response Jack and Craig. I got it to work by doing the loop outside the first one (i=1,420 on the first do) and by addin a= a+1 after the IF Statement, which pretty much is the counter that you mentioned.