# Fortran runtime error: File 'Out.out12.2dcl' does not exist

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I'm using gfortran on SuSE to compile my code and receive the following error:

```
reading 2d cl
At line 18 of file ./TBW_fesolve_Dev/read2Dcl.f90 (unit = 12162015, file = '')
Fortran runtime error: File 'Out.out12.2dcl' does not exist
```

Main file for code is attached in here where at 18 line shows the error.

How to fix this one?

For simplified/minimal example, I have added here the code:

```
subroutine read2dcl(load_factor, load_factor_case_id, node_coords, n_nodes, &
           cl_vec_struct)

implicit none

include 'fesolve_defs_f90.h'

integer :: i, ivar, last_node_id, n_nodes, n1, load_factor_case_id
double precision :: load_factor, y_vec(MAX_NODES), cl_vec_aero(MAX_NODES), &
  node_coords(MAX_NODES,3)
double precision :: cl_vec_struct(*)  
character(len=14), dimension(6) :: filename
character(len=100):: string

filename = (/'Out.out12.2dcl','Out.out13.2dcl', 'Out.out14.2dcl', 'Out.out15.2dcl', &
           'Out.out16.2dcl', 'Out.out17.2dcl'/) 

open(unit=12162015, file=filename(load_factor_case_id-11), access='sequential', status ='old', action='read')
! reading cl from aero output file
do i=1,MAX_NODES
   read(12162015,*,IOSTAT=ivar)last_node_id, y_vec(i), cl_vec_aero(i)
   IF (ivar > 0)  THEN
       write(*,*)'Error encountered'
       exit
   ELSE IF (ivar < 0) THEN
       write(*,*)'End of file reached'
       exit
   END IF
end do
close(12162015)

!allocate(cl_vec_struct(n_nodes))

! interpolating aero cl on structural mesh

!write(*,*)filename(1)
!write(*,*)last_node_id
!write(*,*)cl_vec_aero


cl_vec_struct(1) = cl_vec_aero(1)/load_factor*1.5D0
do i=2,n_nodes-1

   n1 = ((last_node_id-1)*i)/(n_nodes-1)
   cl_vec_struct(i) = (cl_vec_aero(n1) + (cl_vec_aero(n1+1) - cl_vec_aero(n1))* &
                      (real((last_node_id-1)*i)/real(n_nodes-1) - real(n1)))/load_factor*1.5D0

end do
cl_vec_struct(n_nodes) = cl_vec_aero(last_node_id)/load_factor*1.5D0

return

!deallocate(cl_vec_struct)

end subroutine read2dcl
```

Here the load case id=12.

Comment: What value does `load_factor_case_id` have at the time of the `open` statement? You subtract 11 from it and use the result to look up a filename in an array with length 6. Your error suggests that it was trying to open a file with an empty file name.

Comment: Also, nice of you to use a large integer number as the unit identifier. May I suggest to either use a parameter or a variable for that? Like this, a simple typo could mess things up for you in a hard-to-debug fashion.

Comment: Compile it with option `-f check=all` to enable run time checks. That might help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion to use `-fcheck=all`, consider using the argument `NEWUNIT=` to `open` that will select an available unit automatically. The error "file not found" can be caused by the program not executing where the files are located, check this. Also, you can print the variable `filename(load_factor_case_id-11)` to the terminal to verify that a suitable name was chosen.

Comment: @chw21, can you give me an example how to use variables?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl The number of load_factor_case_id is 12. Moreover how to define the location of multiple files in my code? or How to find the current location?

Comment: @Khan Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876075/getting-free-unit-number-in-fortran

Comment: @chw21 ok. I am working on it. Thanks.